# wso2 ESB Integration with API Manager

Tags: wso2, integration, esb, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I am new to Wso2 product suite.
I have the current stack wso2 esb 5.0.0(and analytics),wso2 as-5.3.0,wso2 am 2.0.0(and analytics).I want to inegrate ESB with API Manager.My requirement is I want to use  Gateway, Store, Publisher, Analytics and ESB.
My decided port offsets are 
API M -0
API M Analytics -1
AS - 3
ESB -2
ESB Analytics -4

Is this the correct way for the configuration.
To integrate ESB with API M,
1.Create an API in ESB using wso2 dev studio
2.Create an API in APIPublisher with production url of ESB's API and publish.
3.Subscribe using API store
4.Do the Analytics using APIM -Analytics and ESB Analytics.

Is this understanding correct?

I need to cluster this setup in Production.I came across API Facade pattern and thought that is the correct solution for my scenario.Kindly suggest the correct architecture communication.

Comment: Can anyone help in achieving the above scenario pls?

Comment: How to publish the API created in Wso2 ESB to API Manager and publish it to the store?

Comment: This is suggested according to API Facade pattern.